# Переменное количество переменных в VarArgs

Tags: python

```
def total(initial=5, *numbers, **keywords):
    count = initial
    for number in numbers:
        count += number
    for key in keywords:
        count += keywords[key]
    return count
print(total(10, 1, 2, 3, vegetables=50, fruits=100))
```

Пожалуйста, подскажите, при чем здесь number к параметру varArgs *numbers?

Comment: В этой строке for number in numbers: какое начальное значение number? 10 я так понимаю, а в следующем цикле 1 и тд? А key в первом цикле 50, а потом 100?

Comment: Нет, первое значение number будет 1. 10 попадет в initial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Странный вопрос, что значит при чем?

вы передаете в функцию аргументы, первый из которых - начальное значение. Затем идет сколько угодно неименованных аргументов, а уже затем - сколько угодно именованных.

В функции вы переменной count присваиваете начальное значение.
Затем проходитесь по numbers - списку неименованных аргументов (тоесть просто) чисел и складываете их.
Затем то же самое делаете с именованными аргументами.

другое дело что функция написана неоптимально и ее можно переписать в одну строку:

```
def total(initial=5, *args, **kwargs):
    return initial + sum(args) + sum(kwargs.values())
```

Comment: > неоптимально

Скорее всего, она расписана именно для того, чтобы пояснить суть передачи параметров. Автору же потребовалась помощь с пояснениями.

Answer (score 1):

*numbers - Произвольное количество аргументов. Все аргументы будут помещены в список, то есть в (1,2,3,4) , например
пример `total(10, 1, 2, 3, vegetables=50, fruits=100)` вернет

```
10 (1, 2, 3) {'vegetables': 50, 'fruits': 100}
```

**keywords - Произвольное количество именованных аргументов